# sum of digits with testcases in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find out sum of digits of numbers of testcases in python.

```
def getSum(n):
 
    sum = 0
    while (n != 0):
 
        sum = sum + int(n % 10)
        n = int(n/10)
 
    return sum

n = int(input())
for i in (0, n):
    s = int(input())

    res = getSum(s)
    print(res)
```

My input and output:

```
3 
12345
31203
2123

15
9
```

But desired input and output:

```
3 
12345
31203
2123

15
9
8
```

Comment: You want "for i in range(...".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```py
for i in range(0, n):
    s = int(input())

    res = getSum(s)
    print(res)
```

You need a `range` when you're looping `n` times. Otherwise, you're looping through a tuple of (0, n), which would always run only twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop only runs twice, because you are iterating over a 2-value tuple `(0, 3)`. I think you meant to use the builtin [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). Change your for loop to

```py
for i in range(0, n):
```